# Get value xml by atribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I want get the large image from artist

```js
var cover;

function getCover(jsinger) {
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=U2&api_key=1d07ae6d0a77914229c0ccaa75867fdf",
        //cache: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            i = 1;
            $(xml).find('artist').each(function() {
                cover = $(this).children('image[size="large"]').text();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what is xml.can you share the value

Comment: And what is the error you get? What is the problem? Please share more details.

Comment: @BlackSheep Why don't you post the solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, you can create an array of images using the `.map()` method:

```
var img = $(xml).find('artist').map(function() {
    var src = $(this).children('image[size="large"]').text();
    return "<img src='"+ src + "'/>";
}).get();

$('#container').append(img);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2qzEX/1/

Or in case that you just need the sources:

```
var covers = $(xml).find('artist').map(function() {
    return $(this).children('image[size="large"]').text();
}).get();
```